# Capturing count from an SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What is the simplest way in C# (.cs file) to get the count from the SQL command

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

into an `int` variable?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) and cast it to an `int`:

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: yep, the example in there pretty much covers this as well, just change the `INSERT INTO` to be your `SELECT` statement..

Comment: In this case, there will always be a return value of type int. In the more general case, you might get a return value of DBNull, e.g.  "select ssn from table1 where company_id = '112233'". Since you can't cast the DBNull to your return datatype, you have test and change it, either in the SQL or in your app.

Comment: You're never going to get a DBNULL from Count() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Check the value being returned is a value that can be converted into an Int32.  There's a good chance you're trying to convert a word.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Try using Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) instead of the cast.

Comment: Thank you both for the help :)

Comment: use long instead of int as a return type

Comment: SQLite uses `long` type for integers (not `int` as someone would think). Therefore `var count = (int)(long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` is the way to go.

Comment: Using many databases you should wrap the tablename in the format [tablename]. This way everything will still work if there are escape characters in the table name.

Answer (score 27):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name", conn);
Int32 count = (Int32) comm .ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Is this not identical to my answer?

Comment: Just for clarity, a connection string is usually a string with information about which database you are connection to. An example: "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;" This will log you on to the database with the same credentials you are running on your computer.

Answer (score 11):

You'll get converting errors with:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Use instead:

```
string stm = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE id="+id+";";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
if(count > 0){
    found = true; 
} else {
    found = false; 
}
```

Comment: I have a question ... what if I want to where on a string using a textbox
e.g :- string stm = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE name="+Name.Text .Trim()+";" ;

Answer (score 3):

Complementing in C# with SQL:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name", conn);
Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
if (count > 0)
{
    lblCount.Text = Convert.ToString(count.ToString()); //For example a Label
}
else
{
    lblCount.Text = "0";
}
conn.Close(); //Remember close the connection
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;    
using (new SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    sqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name", connection);
    connection.Open();
    count = (int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```