# select Count from Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need a help with my application as I am trying to show the total number of products after every search! I made a select statement which shows me one row each time from my table Product every time I do search for products using radio button lists and one search box. The search can be either Username or Product Id, then the user can select the row and delete it from the gridview. I also placed a label which is suppose to show number of products left. This label should give me number of products in my grid view! My problem is the label I used it only shows me number one which generates only record and I need to show the number of products in total.

Codes:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Admin_AdminUserControl_Product : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
    {
       DataBaseConn Db = new DataBaseConn();

      Basket _b = new Product(); 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


         // Label shows only one record at a time
         lblQueue.Text = _b.Queue().ToString();


    }



  protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     grid.DataSource = _b.SelectRow(rdoField.SelectedValue,txtSearch.Text);
     grid.DataBind();
      lblMsg.Text = "";
      btnRemove.Enabled = false;
      grid.SelectedIndex = -1;
  }
  protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (_b.RemoveProduct(grid.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text))

        lblMsg.Text = "Product is removed";
      else
          lblMsg.Text = "Unable to remove a Product!";
     grid.DataBind();
     btnRemove.Enabled = false;
  }
    protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      btnRemove.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Class Product

```
  public DataTable Data(string txtField, string Value)
  {

    string SQL = String.Format("Select * from Product where {0} like'%{1}%'", txtField, Value);
    return Data(SQL);

}
public DataTable Data(string Query)
{
    try
    {
        return Db.RunQuery(Query);
    }
    catch
    {
        return new DataTable();
    }

 }

 public bool RemoveProduct(string ProductId)
{

    this.ProductID = ProductId;
    return Delete();
}

public DataTable SelectRow(string Field, string Value)
 {

    string sql = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Product where {0} like '%{1}%' ORDER BY 
       ProductID ASC", Field, Value);
    return SelectRow(sql);

 }

 public DataTable SelectRow(string Query)
 {
    try
    {
        return Db.RunQuery(Query);
    }
    catch
    {
        return new DataTable();
    }

 }
   //This label should show number of all products i.e from 0- any number
     public int Queue()
   {
    int customers;
    String sql = String.Format("Select Count(*) from Product");
    customers = Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows.Count;
    return customers;


   }

 }
```

Comment: What is this `DataBaseConn` object? You cannot run a query to count rows. You have to execute a scalar statement!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing count from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668911/capturing-count-from-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from your use of DataTables that Db.RunQuery is returning a DataTable? If that's the case then

```
.Rows.Count
```

Will just be the number of rows returned by your query. Which in this case is only one..
So if what is returned is indeed a DataTable you'd access the data like this

```
customers = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0])
```

But this is also just assuming that RunQuery is doing a basic fill, returning a datatable, and not doing something else to the datatable.

It also might be simpler to ExecuteScalar against the query
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
//I'm guessing this is something you'd add to your Db class. The ability to ExecuteScalar
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) from Product";
     customers = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: So Hows my code will look like? Do you I still need to run Query ?

Comment: In regards to your original question of why you keep getting the number one instead of the result. If you replace customers = Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows.Count; with customers = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0])  that should give you the right result. But you should look into ExecuteScalar because that's a better way to get the result from the query

Comment: My code works, but wont refresh and there is a delay in deleting records from table! I've never used ExcuteScalar so its kind hard for me to generate it for the first time:(

Comment: I don't follow... The last part of your issues says "This label should give me number of products in my grid view! My problem is the label I used it only shows me number one which generates only record and I need to show the number of products in total." It shows the number one because you're accessing the DataTable row count and not the results from the query. It'd probably be good for you to review ADO.NET which I think will make all this easier for you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Comment: I wish I have enough Points to take screen shot and post it on here! I read the article but still unable to figure out the solution:(

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code:

```
protected void datalistcatagory()
    {

        //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Catagory_ID,Catagory_Name from tbl_catagory where Catagory_ID=Catagory_ID", con);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select (c.Catagory_ID), COUNT(c.Catagory_ID) As CID, c.Catagory_Name from tbl_NewPost sc join tbl_catagory c on c.Catagory_ID=sc.Catagory_ID Group by c.Catagory_Name, c.Catagory_ID Order by CID DESC"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {


                        Label4.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();

                    }
                    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                    Repeater1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this code related to the original question? You select data from `NewPost` and `tbl_catagory` that were never mentionned in the orginal question. You are updating Ui element that are not in the orginal question. There is no explanation: is this answer about the usage of `SelectCommand`? As it can't be an example of `Rows.Count` as that's what the answer from 2014 already do.