# Record count in c# query result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

How can i get Total records count in query result

```
   SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString);
              string sql = "select  Fare , OrderAmount FROM orderitems OI INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID WHERE PaymentStatusID = 1  AND o.orderid ="+Orderid;                 
            SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(sql, con1);
               con1.Open();
              comd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Above is my sql query i need result count, can some one help me 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing count from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668911/capturing-count-from-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 8):

`ExecuteNonQuery`  is used for query like insert/update/delete.

Use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
string sql = "select  count(*) FROM orderitems OI INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID WHERE PaymentStatusID = 1  AND o.orderid ="+Orderid;    
SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(sql, con1);
con1.Open();
int count = Convert.ToInt32(comd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the `Fare` and the `OrderAmount` (a bit strange, since the sql script you have written contains them), you could replace them with a `COUNT(*)`.

```
string sql = "select  COUNT(*) FROM orderitems OI INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID =  OI.OrderID WHERE PaymentStatusID = 1  AND o.orderid ="+Orderid;
```

Then you can read this fairly easily, like below:

```
int numberOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(comd.ExecuteScalar());
```

On the other hand, if you need them, you could count the number of records in the sql reader you will use to read those results, like below:

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader = comd.ExecuteReader(); 

int numberOfRecords = 0;
while(sqlReader.Read())
{
    // do things
    numberOfRecords++;
}
```

**Note**

In any case, you can't use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method, since you want to read something from a database. You don't want to create, update or delete something. Only in the latter cases we use this method.

One more important note is about the **security** of the queries you build and then execute is to avoid *string concatenation* for passing the values of parameters. This makes your app vulnerable to sql injections, one of the major ways of attacks. Instead of doing this, you could use a sql parametrized query, like below:

```
 string sql = "select  Fare , OrderAmount  FROM orderitems OI INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID WHERE PaymentStatusID = 1  AND o.orderid=@Orderid";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con1);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Orderid",OrderId);
```