# Not stopping from Registering with same username

Tags: c#, sql

**Complete Code For stopping user from using same User Names**

```
    if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserDataTable where UserName='" +
username.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Already Exists");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

1. The above code is for stopping people to use the same UserName that
   is already used to register
2. But unfortunately it does not stop them from registration with the existing 
   username, hence they can still use the same User Name.

Code For **Button1_Click**
This is the code for my submit button

```
    try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            //inserting data to database
            string insertQuery = "insert into [UserDataTable] (UserName,Email,Password,Country) values (@username, @email, @password, @country)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("You're Now Registered");


            con.Close();
         }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());

        }
```

**My DataBase**
My database that i created

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDataTable] (
[Id]       INT NULL,
[UserName] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email]    NCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Password] NCHAR (20)    NULL,
[Country]  NCHAR (15)    NULL
```

My Problem/Question:
why is it not stopping them from using the existing Username

i wrote this code by dissecting other codes that i saw online, So if it seems strange and weird I apologize its my first time using C#

Hope this helps in understanding my problem

Software:Visual Studio 2017

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Read up on SQL injection attacks and don't build SQL strings from user input. Use parametrized queries.

Comment: Very strange code - assuming you've used MSDN sample https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx as starting point very unclear why you endup with SQL injection and awkward `ToInt32` instead of cast... Even if you started from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668911/capturing-count-from-an-sql-query...

Comment: `it doesn't work` what does this mean?

Comment: *why is it not stopping them from using the existing Username* - It's impossible to tell you an answer to this without knowing *when* you run the first code block. Is it actually run in your `Button1_Click` event so it can prevent the duplicate entry from being entered?

Answer (score 5):

Try running that query and seeing what you get back. It's possible that you're getting different results than you expect.

I'd recommend changing:

```
if (temp == 1)
```

to:

```
if (temp > 0)
```

which should weed out cases where a username is already in the database twice.

Also, as other people have mentioned in comments, you definitely want to be using parameters. Here is your code converted to use parameters:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserDataTable where UserName = @userName";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con);
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", username.Text));
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, i edited my original code and the question above please have a look again, i used your advice now im getting an error "System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
"

Comment: You need to add con.Open(); to your code before you try to execute the query

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get rid of SQL-Injection :

```
 string checkuser = "select * from UserDataTable where UserName=@uname";
```

Then use either a `DataTable` or a `DataReader`.Let's use `DataReader` for instance :

```
////Firstly,we generally declare the connection as con for easy-recognition 

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection;
 con = "connectionstringhere";

 ///then we use the sqlCommand which we generally declare as cmd

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser,con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@uname",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = usernameStringHere

 ///then we use a datareader(note: A datareader is better than DataAdapter regarding performance 

 SqlDataReader dr;
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader;

 ///Then we check if any row exists in the dataReader after we filter the database 

 If dr.Hasrows
 { 

  ////Wont save data

 }
```

The above code will get the job done.

Or you can simply go with `ExecuteScalar`

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from UserDataTable where userNme=@uname",con)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@uname",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usernamestringhere
 int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar;

 If(count > 0) 
 {
  ///eon't save data
 }
```

**Summary :** You had two issues :

1 . **Sql-Injection** - which i clearly explained how to fix

2 .  using `temp == 1` instead of `temp > 0`..

Hope this helps you

Comment: I wrote the answer keeping in mind that OP might use the datatable in future :(

Comment: Okey, i edit my code and used a datareader,can u lift the downvote now ?

Comment: If you provide somewhat compilable code and remove that part where you ask to explain to you  what `count(*)` means (you should post question as question and not part of an answer)...

Comment: please re-view the answer .... I hope u will find it good enough to lift the downvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

99.9999999% chance "UserName" is not a primary key.

Just run a select to see if there are multiple users with the input "UserName".

a quick fix
change

> select count(*) from...

to

> select top 1 1 from...

It will always return 1 if there is anything matches, NULL if not.