# Polling Method not performing as expected C#/SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, logic, polling, sqldependency

I am working on a c# service(built as a console app for now for debugging) that will is polling against a DB tables row count. Upon a new row being added to the table(INSERT) the application will kick off to begin some other processing however i'm having issue with the polling logic.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                //1 second pause
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"OMITTED"); //connection to DB
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("OMITTED", conn); //Query to fil poll table comparator

                DataTable table = new DataTable(); //establishing new instance to fill
                adapter.Fill(table);

                int prevRowCount = table.Rows.Count; // establishing comparator value

                while (true) //loop
                {
                adapter.Fill(table);
                if (table.Rows.Count > prevRowCount)
                    {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("New records");
                    
                    prevRowCount = table.Rows.Count;

                    }
                
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //1 second pause

                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Watching the data table variable in debug and prevrowcount, they both seem so be sitting at 2, however the if is still stepped into. And then upon the next adapter.Fill it seems the value is getting incremented by the row count every iteration. So my question(s):

When using this structure do I need to clear the instance of the variable every loop after the if, if so how?

Why is the if performing upon the first if iteration when the data table variable only has 2 rows and the prevrowcount variable is 2?

I've tried moving the adapter fill, removing it from the while. Different ways of setting, I am not understanding why the if is being performed.

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here; if you are using a different product that you can connect to via SSMS, please [edit] your post to correct the tag(s).

Comment: sorry about that thank you yes I am connecting via ssms

Comment: But your question isn't about SSMS, so please don't tag it.

Comment: From the [docs for `DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable)): *You can use the Fill method multiple times on the same DataTable. If a primary key exists, incoming rows are merged with matching rows that already exist. If no primary key exists, incoming rows are appended to the DataTable.*  Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: Also, if you really only need the count, see [Capturing count from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4668911).

Comment: @dbc Sadly I need to do some processing with the records data upon it's insertion so just getting the count will not suffice. Additionally, what is odd is the table does have a defined PK upon creation "RecordId" but yet the Fill is still adding the records to the dataset even though the RecordId is duped in them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use SQL table dependency. you will not need to write code to poll and do all this.

you can refer to [this](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency), I have personally used this in my project.

you will get a notification of inserted/modified/deleted records. you can use it accordingly.

Even Microsoft has provided [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency), but I have never used it.